# React router transitionTo, .substring is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some simple components, and I want to use the router.transitionTo function. What am I doing wrong here:

```
const { Router,
        Route,
        IndexRoute,
        Redirect,
        Link,
        IndexLink
      } = ReactRouter

const Person = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      hihihi  
      </div>
    )
  }
})
const App = React.createClass({
  clickHandler() {
    this.context.router.transitionTo('/person/23')
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={this.clickHandler}>React Router Playground</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/person/:id" component={Person}/>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyerXj?editors=001

Comment: if you vote to close, please explain why. I'm only trying to find my answer as I was not able to find it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In App component you have method:

```
  clickHandler() {
    this.context.router.transitionTo('/person/23')
  },
```

Please change it to:

```
  clickHandler() {
    this.context.router.push('/person/23')
  },
```

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVOabg

This is because actual version of react-router use `router.push` to change route